# SRD summary translation legal?

Tags: dnd-5e, ogl, translations

I just wonder if it is legal (according to the OGL) to summarize/translate the key rules of the 5e SRD in another language (say German or French) using the OGL?

Answer (score 10):

#### Yes

As long as you satisfy the requirements of the license, the [OGL](http://www.opengamingfoundation.org/ogl.html) specifically grants permission to translate open game content.

From section 1, definitions part "g":

> "Use", "Used" or "Using" means to use, Distribute, copy, edit, format, modify, **translate** and otherwise create Derivative Material of Open Game Content.

And section 4:

> Grant and Consideration: In consideration for agreeing to use this License, the Contributors grant You a perpetual, worldwide, royalty-free, non-exclusive license with the exact terms of this License to **Use**, the Open Game Content.

Comment: Interesting. Ulisses Spiele (they are responsible for the official german translation of 5e) have explicitly stated that they are not allowed to provide a translated SRD. Or would this be a case of "translating it is allowed, but publishing it is not"?

Comment: That's strange. The OGL certainly does not prevent them from doing so. Both "Distribution" and "Translation" are explicitly permitted under the OGL, as you can see from the sections I quoted. That said they may feel a financial incentive not to produce a translation of the SRD.

Comment: Or there may be other legal contractual obligations in play besides the SRD that prevent it.